# Dynamic Describe Result

Tags: apex, community, dynamic-visualforce, describesobject, describefieldresult

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> PL = field.getPicklistValues();
```

I am trying to do this:I want to replace field name dynamically.

```
String A='Stagename';
String B='Opportunity.'+StageName+'.getDescribe();'
Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = B;
```

I am getting error .How can I achieve this I tried following:

```
String Field='StageName';
SObjectType OppType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Opportunity');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = accountType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Schema.SObjectField sobjF = mfields.get(Field);
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldProdDiv1 = Opportunity.sobjF.getDescribe();
```

How to achieve this if at all it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to blog http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/10/20/getting-salesforce-field-metadata-the-easy-way/ you can get field information using a Describe call.

```
public static Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult> getFieldMetaData(  
  Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsor, Set<String> fields) {

  // the map to be returned with the final data
  Map<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult> finalMap = 
    new Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
  // map of all fields in the object
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = dsor.fields.getMap();

  // iterate over the requested fields and get the describe info for each one. 
  // add it to a map with field name as key
  for(String field : fields){
    // skip fields that are not part of the object
    if (objectFields.containsKey(field)) {
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult dr = objectFields.get(field).getDescribe();
      // add the results to the map to be returned
      finalMap.put(field, dr); 
    }
  }
  return finalMap;
}


// field to return -- skips fields not actually part of the sobject
Set<String> fields = new Set<String>{'name','annualrevenue','BADFIELD'};

Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult> finalMap =  
  Utils.getFieldMetaData(Account.getSObjectType().getDescribe(), fields);

// only print out the 'good' fields
for (String field : new Set<String>{'name','annualrevenue'}) {  
  System.debug(finalMap.get(field).getName()); // field name
  System.debug(finalMap.get(field).getType()); // field type
  System.debug(finalMap.get(field).getLength()); // field length
}
```

Hope this helps :)